# Are Soap Suds Normal After the Dishwasher is done?

Tags: dishwasher

This washing machine uses the normal pods. I set the jet dry to minimal. However, at the end of the wash cycle I see soap suds on the bottom. Is this normal? I was wondering if the soap suds were from the jets washing the soap off the dishes.

The dishes come out really clean and I do not detect any soap on the dishes.

[image: dishwasher]

Comment: Is the rinse cycle working?

Comment: I believe so because I find sitting water on top of the cups sometimes

Comment: is your hot water very hot? bump the jet dri up a notch...

Answer (score 1):

If you use a rinse or "anti-spotting" agent ("Jet Dry®" is one brand name of such products) this is almost certainly the residue of that. Put a drop of in in a bottle of water and shake to observe the effect.

*Personal opinion - I don't fill that spot in my dishwasher and see no ill effects from not using it.*

Actual dishwasher detergent makes almost no bubbles - as anyone who has screwed up and put hand dishwashing liquid into the dishwasher will understand better than any who have not (don't do it for the experience, though - just imagine opening the dishwasher door to a wall of foam...)

Comment: In my case it was a wall of suds coming out of the sink drain then the wall coming out when the door was opened.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your title: No. This is not a normal amount of soapsuds to see in a dishwasher after it is finished.

If there is this much soap in the washer at the end, then there is a lot of soap left on the dishes. Even though you can't taste it. Try dipping your finished dishes in a pan of clean water to see how much soap rinses off.

I have had this much suds left in a clothes washer, and it turned out I was using the wrong detergent. Check carefully that you are using the detergent specified by the manufacturer.

I hope that you have just used the wrong, or too much, detergent, because that would be such an easy fix.

The most likely cause of your soapsuds problem is not enough water. For some reason, your dishwasher is not filling completely. You can tell by opening the door (which pauses the washing action) during a wash or rinse phase and looking at the water level.

In order to really test this properly, you need to know what the normal water level looks like. I don't know exactly how you would find this out. But most dishwashers have a float valve that shuts off the water at the proper level. If you can find this switch, you can at least tell whether it is being switched by the water level.

Another thing look at is the amount of residual water remaining in the machine between cycles. If the dishwasher is not emptying completely between phases then you are rinsing with soapy water. You have to lift the debris filter to check the low water level between phases.

If you find that the dishwasher isn't filling or emptying properly, then you're looking at a plumbing problem.

Check for debris in the supply line. Check for a clogged input filter. Check for a broken or partially operating fill valve.

Check for a kinked or blocked drain line. Check for a broken or partially operating drain valve. Check for debris blocking the drain opening inside the washer under that large round screen.

Keep lots of towels handy. Wear work clothing. You will probably get splashed in the face at least once.

Answer (score 1):

Jet dry is a surfactant it breaks the water tension to reduce spotting and get things clean , standard dishwasher soap is non sudsing so if you are getting suds some regular dish soap made its way into your machine. I did this as a young kid and it made one hell of a mess but just a drop or 2 on a pan or other item that may have been pre washed is probably where the suds came from because standard dishwashing soap is non sudsing and jet dry breaks down bubbles.

Comment: Some people wash their kitchen sponge in the dishwasher to sanitize the sponge. If dman is doing this, the sponge should be thoroughly rinsed of all dish detergent before placing it in the dishwasher.